# Meteor and graphicsMagic on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, meteor, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to run meteor app developed under MacOS on Windows.

Have this problem:

> WARNING: cfs:graphicsmagick could not find "graphicsMagic" or
>   "imageMagic" on the system.
>
> I just checked PATH to see if I could find the GraphicsMagick or
>   ImageMagic unix/mac os/windows binaries on your system, I failed.
>
> Why:
>   1. I may be blind or naive, help making me smarter
>   2. You havent added the path to the binaries
>   3. You havent actually installed GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick
>
> *** Make sure "$PATH" environment is configured "PATH:/path/to/binaries" ***
>
> Installation hints:
>   * Mac OS X "brew install graphicsmagick" or "brew install imagemagick"
>   * Linux download rpm or use packagemanager
>   * Centos "yum install GraphicsMagick"* Windows download the installer and run

I've installed GraphicsMagick and ImageMagic, checked PATH.
In cmd gm command runs GraphicsMagick, but still this problem remain in meteor.

Answer (score 1):

The `cfs:graphicsmagick` module is designed to work on windows. This is the script that looks for graphicsmagick. I've modified it to work with node and increased the verbosity to help you debug the issue:

```
var graphicsmagick = false;
var imagemagick = false;
var fs = require("fs"); //or Npm.require("fs") if you're running this script with meteor
// Split the path by : for linux
// Split the path by ; for windows
var sep = /^win/.test(process.platform) ? ';' : ':';
var binaryPaths = process.env['PATH'].split(sep);

// XXX: we should properly check if we can access the os temp folder - since
// gm binaries are using this and therefore may fail?

// XXX: we could push extra paths if the `gm` library check stuff like:
// $MAGIC_HOME The current version does not check there
// $MAGICK_HOME (GraphicsMagick docs)

// We check to see if we can find binaries
for (var i = 0; i < binaryPaths.length; i++) {
  var binPath = binaryPaths[i];
  console.log("Looking in", binPath)
  // If we have not found GraphicsMagic
  if (!graphicsmagick) {
    // Init
    var gmPath = path.join(binPath, 'gm');
    var gmExePath = path.join(binPath, 'gm.exe');

    // Check to see if binary found
    graphicsmagick = fs.existsSync(gmPath) || fs.existsSync(gmExePath);

    // If GraphicsMagic we dont have to check for ImageMagic
    // Since we prefer GrapicsMagic when selecting api
    if (!graphicsmagick && !imagemagick) {
      // Init paths to check
      var imPath = path.join(binPath, 'convert');
      var imExePath = path.join(binPath, 'convert.exe');

      // Check to see if binary found
      imagemagick = fs.existsSync(imPath) || fs.existsSync(imExePath);

    }
  }
}

console.log("Found GraphicsMagick", graphicsmagick)
console.log("Found ImageMagick", imagemagick)
```

When you run it it will give you a path that it is looking in, in the through all `PATH` variables from the environment variable.

Look for the imagemagick installation you have and check that it matches up. If you run the script with Meteor make sure to change `Npm.require("fs")` from `require('fs')`.

The check is very thorough looking for the `gm.exe` or `convert.exe`, if you have it installed you will have to find out why it is not being detected.

Comment: Now i have this:
W20150613-14:08:47.474(3)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: path is not defined

in lines, with path.join

Comment: I've changed your code to "var gmExePath = binPath + '\\gm.exe';"
Now it works and founds the gm.exe, as expected :)
But still have error that meteor couldn't find GraphicsMagick

Comment: I got the same issue. I got gm found (with the above script after adding path variable) and also when running "gm" in cmd, but meteor package says it can't find it.